# Creating a Image from javafx2 2d Color list using bufferImage

Tags: java, java-8, javafx-2

I am trying to convert my 2d list of Colors to an actual image and then export it, however, when I try to use it, it distorts the colors (shows the wrong ones)

```
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageAction {
    public static void fromColorGrid(List<List<Color>> colorGrid) {
        int width = colorGrid.size();
        int height = colorGrid.get(0).size();

        BufferedImage buffImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        // Set each pixel of the BufferedImage to the color from the Color[][].
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                String colorStr = colorGrid.get(x).get(y).toString().replace("0x", "");
                int rgb = Integer.parseInt(colorStr, 16);
                System.out.println(colorStr + "   " + rgb);
                buffImage.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
            }
        }
        try {
            File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
            ImageIO.write(buffImage, "png", outputfile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Ups");
        }
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit seems odd to me:

```
String colorStr = colorGrid.get(x).get(y).toString().replace("0x", "");
int rgb = Integer.parseInt(colorStr, 16);
System.out.println(colorStr + "   " + rgb);
buffImage.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
```

That code relies on `toString()` method of JavaFX's color class, [which explicitly states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#toString--):

> This method is intended to be used only for informational purposes. The content and format of the returned string might vary between implementations.

Instead, just convert directly to an AWT color using the RGB values:

```
Color fxColor = colorGrid.get(x).get(y);
java.awt.Color awtColor = new java.awt.Color((float) fxColor.getRed(),
        (float) fxColor.getGreen(),
        (float) fxColor.getBlue(),
        (float) fxColor.getOpacity());
buffImage.setRGB(x, y, awtColor.getRGB());
```

The above doesn't rely on any particular toString() implementation, and in my quick tests the code seems to work fine with it in place.